# Use the first and last element (dates) in an array to create an obj.name in an Angular factory/service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an Angular service/factory method that takes as a parameter passed to it in the form of an array of arrays containing objects `[[{},{}],[{},{}]]`.

The data contained in this parameter, consist of arrays of weeks, with an object for each day consisting of a date and an integer value. Ex. `{"2017-01-10": 711}`.

The method's function is to group each array of weeks in a single object, with its integer values totaled. Ex. `{"name": "Week 1", "total": 3228}`

**How can I take the first and last element of each array, and create a name/label from this?** So, the output would look like this: `{"name": "Week 1 - 2017-01-10 to 2017-01-15", "total": 3228}`

**Here is an example of the data passed to the method:**

```
[
   [
      {
         "2016-11-01": 319
      },
      {
         "2016-11-02": 782
      },
      {
         "2016-11-03": 579
      },
      {
         "2016-11-04": 642
      },
      {
         "2016-11-05": 444
      },
      {
         "2016-11-06": 274
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "2016-11-07": 319
      },
      {
         "2016-11-08": 782
      },
      {
         "2016-11-09": 579
      },
      {
         "2016-11-10": 642
      },
      {
         "2016-11-11": 444
      },
      {
         "2016-11-12": 274
      },
      {
         "2016-11-13": 481
      }
   ]
]
```

**Here is the method:**

```
function assignWeekNamesAndTotals(arrayOfWeeks) {

    var data = arrayOfWeeks;

    var result = data.reduce(function (p, c, i) {

        var total = c.reduce(function (total, obj) {
            for (var k in obj) {
                total += obj[k]; // calculate total
            }
            return total;
        }, 0);

        // Format object in any format you want
        var tmp = {};
        tmp.name = "Week " + (i + 1)
        tmp.total = total;

        p.push(tmp)
        return p;
    }, [])

    console.log("Assign Week names and Totals Output (Step 2: " + JSON.stringify(result, null, "   "));
    return result;   
}
```

I appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to create a solution by doing the following:**

I created a method inside my method that creates an array of the dates. I then simply use the first and last element in the array for my period.

```
function assignWeekNamesAndTotals(arrayOfWeeks) {

    var data = arrayOfWeeks;

    var result = data.reduce(function (p, c, i) {

        var dateArray = [];

        var createDateArray = c.forEach(function (obj) {

            var dateFromObj = Object.keys(obj)[0];

            dateArray.push(dateFromObj);

            return dateArray;
        });

        var total = c.reduce(function (total, obj) {

            for (var k in obj) {
                total += obj[k]; // calculate total
            }
            return total;
        }, 0);

        // Format object in any format you want
        var tmp = {};
        var first = dateArray[0];
        var last = dateArray[dateArray.length - 1]
        tmp.name = "Week: from " + first + " to " + last;
        tmp.total = total;

        p.push(tmp)
        return p;
    }, [])
    console.log("Assign Week names and Totals Output (Step 2: " + JSON.stringify(result, null, "   "));
    return result;
}
```

**The output is as follows:**

```
[
   {
      "name": "Week: from 2017-01-10 to 2017-01-15",
      "total": 3228
   },
   {
      "name": "Week: from 2017-01-16 to 2017-01-16",
      "total": 363
   }
]
```